# Polynomial equation, cannot solve for $x$

Tags: polynomials

> $$3x^2-4x-4+x^3=x^3+2x+2$$

This boils down to (I think):

$$3x^2 - 6x - 6 = 0$$

I'm trying to solve for $x$ using the polynomial equation:
$$\begin{align}
x &= \frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a} \\
a &= 3 \\[0.2ex]
b &= -6 \\
c &= -6
\end{align}$$

My textbook tells me that the solutions for the positive and negative versions of $x$ are $x = 1 + \sqrt{3}$ and $x = 1 - \sqrt{3}$. I'm unable to replicate this.

Here's my work:
$$\begin{align}
x&=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a} \\[0.8ex]
x&=\frac{-6\pm\sqrt{(-6)^2-4(3)(-6)}}{2a} \\[0.8ex]
x&=\frac{-6\pm\sqrt{36-72}}{2a}
\end{align}$$

Since $(36 - 72) < 0$, I'm unable to take the square root so I do not see how the equation is solvable.

Unless I boiled down the equation into the wrong form with the original.
I turned:
$$3x^2-4x-4+x^3=x^3+2x+2$$
into

$$3x^2-6x-6=0$$

How can I arrive at solutions for $x$ where $x = 1 + \sqrt{3}$ and $x = 1 - \sqrt{3}\,$ per my textbook's given solutions?

Comment: discriminant will be $36+72$, that's your mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so we start off with:
$$x^3+3x^2-4x-4=x^3+2x+2$$
which we can re-write as:
$$3x^2-6x-6=0$$
so we know that:
$$x=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}=\frac{6\pm\sqrt{36-(4)(3)(-6)}}{6}=1\pm\frac{\sqrt{108}}{6}=1\pm\sqrt{3}$$

The mistake you made was $36-72$ instead of $36+72$

Comment: Thanks but would 108 not be 114 since the initial 6 +-?

Comment: that is not inside the squareroot so we do not include it

Comment: http://www.mathwarehouse.com/dictionary/D-words/distributive-property-definition-and-examples.php remember where you can apply your commutative and distributive laws

Answer (score 1):

$$x^3+3x^2-4x-4=x^3+2x+2$$
$$3x^2-6x-6=0$$
$$x^2-2x-2=0$$

$$x=\frac{-(-2)\pm\sqrt{(-2)^2-4(1)(-2)}}{2(1)}$$
$$x=\frac{2\pm\sqrt{4+8}}{2}=\frac{2\pm 2\sqrt 3}{2}=1\pm\sqrt 3$$